# pass parameters to several AngularJS directive instances?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Newbie question on angularJS, but don't see analogous case in tutorials having searched.

How do I pass different parameters to individual div instances using the same directive definition?   Here I'd expect to see `red green blue` but instead I see `blue blue blue` in the HTML.   I see the controller is getting called before the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/gradualstudent/Y2bBy/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

      app.directive("element", function () {
        return {
          restrict: "A",
          template: '<h1>{{type}}</h1>',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.type = attrs.element;
            console.log("Setting:  "+scope.type);
          },
          controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log("Checking: "+$scope.type);
          }
        };
      })

    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div element="red">1</div>
  <div element="green">2</div>
  <div element="blue">3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all instances of your directive use the same scope and every time the `link` function is called, it overrides the previously set `scope.type`. if you create an isolated scope then it will work because each instance of the directive will get its own scope:

```
    app.directive("element", function () {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {},
      template: '<h1>{{type}}</h1>',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.type = attrs.element;
        console.log("Setting:  "+scope.type);
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {
        console.log("Checking: "+$scope.type);
      }
    };
  })
```

Comment: scope: { type: '@element' } would be better

Comment: This answer didn't work for me, I think it confused my directives (and nothing loaded) but then again, I am using ng 1.2

Answer (score 5):

In the example you have shared, the directives share the parent scope. Since all directive share the same parent scope there is only one variable `type` available.

The options that you have is to do either

```
scope:true   //Creates new scope for each directive instance
```

or

```
scope:{} //as provided by akonsu. Creates an isolated scope.
```

Just for completeness please spend time on understanding scope prototypal inheritance https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Thanks so much.  Just got thru this on egghead.io, which starts out "isolate scope is one of those things where you can read the docs for days, then someone shows it to you and then you're like 'oh, that's easy'"  -- http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope

Comment: `scope:true   //Creates new scope for each directive instance`